# Try creating folder using Mac VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos, mkdir

I'm working on Excel 11 Mac OS and below is the [code](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac010.htm) I'm using for creating a folder

```
Function MakeFolderIfNotExist(Folderstring As String)
Dim ScriptToMakeFolder As String
Dim str As String
If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
    ScriptToMakeFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & _
                         "Finder" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
    ScriptToMakeFolder = ScriptToMakeFolder & _
            "do shell script ""mkdir -p "" & quoted form of posix path of (" & _
                    Chr(34) & Folderstring & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(13)
    ScriptToMakeFolder = ScriptToMakeFolder & "end tell"
    On Error Resume Next
    MacScript (ScriptToMakeFolder)
    On Error GoTo 0

Else
    str = MacScript("return POSIX path of (" & _
                    Chr(34) & Folderstring & Chr(34) & ")")
    MkDir str
End If
End Function
```

After I call the function using

```
MakeFolderIfNotExist("/Desktop/test/2017")
```

I'm getting the error saying path not found. I've been searching the internet for good 2 hours now with no luck. can somebody please help?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac017.htm     Seems to imply there might be more to the filepath before the /Desktop

Comment: Read through all of these

Comment: You mean "/Users/admin/Desktop/test/2017" ?I tried that too. I also tried using : instead of /

Comment: Did you try running the code at the link to verify your desktop path?

Comment: I just refreshed everything, deleted the test folder and now it works. Phew!