# Save each worksheet with formatting in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template file and 4 source documents that I use to fill the template.  For each row in sheet2, I create a new blank template and fill it out, resulting in somewhere between 10-100 files.  I want to save these in a loop, but having issues with Excel force closing on me.  This is my code so far, recycled from a different project.

````
    Dim w As Long, wb As Workbook
    Dim fp As String, fn As String
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim fsoFSO

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'stop screen flashing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False    'stop confirmation alerts

    'start with a reference to ThisWorkbook
    With ThisWorkbook

    folderName = Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

    'set path to save
    'fp = "<PATH HERE>" & folderName
    fp = "C:\Users\Username\OneDrive - CompanyName\Documents\Projects\ThisProject\csvOutput\" & folderName


    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fsoFSO.FolderExists(fp) Then
        MsgBox "FOLDER - " & fp & " ALREADY EXISTS, DELETE CONTENTS TO PROCEED"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        fsoFSO.CreateFolder (fp)
    End If

        'cycle through each of the worksheets
        For w = 6 To Worksheets.Count
            With Worksheets(w)
                .Copy
                'the ActiveWorkbook is now the new workbook populated with a copy of the current worksheet
                With ActiveWorkbook
                    fn = .Worksheets(1).Name

                Cells.Select
                Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                Worksheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Worksheets(1).Delete
                Worksheets(1).Name = fn

                    .SaveAs Filename:=fp & Chr(92) & fn, FileFormat:=51
                    .Close savechanges:=False   '<~~ already saved in line above
                End With
            End With
        Next w
    End With

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub ```
````

Comment: Your comment says "set path to save CSV" - what file format are you expecting?  If you want CSV then CSV files have no formatting.  Also, this code doesn't seem to match your description of your process.

Comment: This code is from another process where I save a series of worksheets.  The sub that performs the formatting and filling out of the template file is a different sub.  I just want to adapt this save function to retain the formatting of each created template worksheet.  Is it really as simple as changing to .xlsx?  It is set to file format 51 in the code

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me: not sure exactly where the problem might vbe with your posted code, but within your `With` blocks not everything is scope to the block using a leading `.`

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim w As Long, wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
    Dim fp As String, fn As String
    Dim fsoFSO

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    fp = "C:\Users\Username\OneDrive - CompanyName\Documents\Projects\" & _
         "ThisProject\csvOutput\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & "\"
    
    Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fsoFSO.FolderExists(fp) Then
        MsgBox "FOLDER - " & fp & " ALREADY EXISTS, DELETE CONTENTS TO PROCEED"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        fsoFSO.CreateFolder fp
    End If

    'cycle through each of the worksheets
    For w = 6 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        
        'explicitly create a new single-sheet workbook as the destination
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(Template:=xlWBATWorksheet)
        wb.Worksheets(w).Copy before:=wbNew.Sheets(1)
        DeleteSheet wbNew.Sheets(2)
        
        With wbNew
            fn = .Worksheets(1).Name
            .Worksheets.Add after:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                                Destination:=.Worksheets(2).Range("A1")
            
            DeleteSheet .Worksheets(1)
            
            .Worksheets(1).Name = fn
            .SaveAs Filename:=fp & fn, FileFormat:=51
            .Close savechanges:=False   '<~~ already saved in line above
        End With
    Next w
    Exit Sub
    
bm_Safe_Exit:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

'utility sub
Sub DeleteSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This for some reason is not saving anything and it also is closing my excel instance, along with all other open workbooks.  I commented out the .Close statement and it still closed my excel instance.

Comment: Try commenting out the error handler and see if there's an error

Comment: I commented out the error handling and it saved the first 4 worksheets (source data sheets) with no errors.  However, the sheets I want to save are from 6 to ws.count.  I changed the loop to be w = 6 To wb.Worksheets.Count, and it only saved the 6th sheet.  It still closes all instances of Excel, which I am struggling to understand.  Is it possible to get it to just loop from w = 6 to wb.Worksheets.Count without deleting them all or closing my excel?  Should I comment out the .Worksheets(1).Delete?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Save each worksheet (from 6>end) to a separate file, or something else?

Comment: ...the 1 was left over from my testing and I forgot to switch it back to 6.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to save sheet 6>end as separate worksheets with formatting.  .xlsx is fine... I switched the 1 to a 6 when I ran it, no problems there.

Comment: I just tested again and it's working fine for me: saves a copy of each sheet starting at the sixth sheet as a separate file, and does not affect the original file.

Comment: It is not consistent behavior for me.  Sometimes I can "step into" the code and manually go to the next line and it will save the worksheets properly (tested by modifying it to go from w=6 -> w=12.  Other times it force closes my Excel application.  When I just "run" the code, it will force close my Excel every time.

Comment: OK I've no idea what's going on there.  Do you have any unusual add-ins, or any event code in the sheets you're exporting?

Comment: No, just a collection of subs that move data around/create new sheets.  I have a couple macro buttons, if that counts as "event code".  I have no add-ins either.  My Excel is tied to OneDrive and I find that it will make things run much slower... It kinda seems like when I get to the save/close part when I just "run" the code, the code gets ahead of the application and applies the close to my main workbook.  Whereas when I "step into", I wait until each line completes its action before the next line is performed.  I'm not sure if this even makes sense...

Comment: When you `Copy` a worksheet without giving it a destination, it should always create a new workbook with the copy, and that workbook should always be the ActiveWorkbook.  So after calling `Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook`, all other operations in that following `With wbNew` should affect only  `wbNew`.  If your whole Excel instance is getting shut down I can't figure out why/how that's happening.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help Tim, this isn't the first time you've helped me .  I can't figure it out either, but it seems like I have code that should be working.

Comment: One last try - see updated code above.  It will explicitly create a new workbook for the sheet copy, instead of relying on `ActiveWorkbook` to access the new workbook.

Comment: I appreciate the persistence.. This time it created the folder, saved the 6th sheet, then errored out with "Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed."  It did not force close my excel instance, but it did leave both workbooks open (the source workbook and the isolated sheet it saved).

Comment: I keep getting some strange errors with my Excel when opening .xlsm files saying "can't find project or library"... maybe I should restart my PC, maybe something is wrong with my Excel atm.

Comment: That usually means you have a "missing" reference in your VB project

Comment: It is working flawlessly now, no idea what changed.  Tim, thank you once again... I owe you two 6-packs now.

Comment: I built this procedure to be consumed by a Mac and didn't realize the creating the file system object wasn't possible there.  Is there another method I can use without starting from scratch?

Comment: You could try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684259/try-creating-folder-using-mac-vba   I'm not a Mac user, but making a lot of the VBA you'd see here on SO work on a Mac can be a challenge sometimes.

Comment: It seems like the only piece of this that MAC doesn't run is the creation of the file system object.  If I were to hard code a path and require the user to empty this folder manually each time, I think I can get around it.  Thanks!